# Go to device root path of Downloads on Android/iOS on Qt C++ app

Tags: android, c++, ios, qt

hope all is well.  I am trying to access the device root path of Downloads on Android and iOS on a Qt C++ app.  My code so far:

```
mPath = "~/Downloads";
dirmodel = new QFileSystemModel (this);
dirmodel->setFilter(QDir::AllDirs | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);
dirmodel->setRootPath(mPath);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what's your problem exactly?

Comment: Thanks Shebuka, I need to access the files inside a root folder in an iOS device, so far the paths I tried didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [QStandardPaths](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html) class for this. It provides you with QStandardPaths::DownloadLocation. It will automatically translate to the correct location depending on the platform.

Comment: Thanks Rolf Winter, I was able to make it work except for iOS, where no files are being found.  Here is my code:

const QStringList mPathList = QStandardPaths::standardLocations(QStandardPaths::DownloadLocation);
    mPath = QString("%1").arg(mPathList.first());
    dirmodel = new QFileSystemModel (this);
    dirmodel->setFilter(QDir::AllDirs | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);
    dirmodel->setRootPath(mPath);

Comment: Here is the derivative new question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46588201/no-files-found-on-ios-devices-qt-creator-c-qstandardpathsstandardlocationsq

Comment: How do the files get there in the first place? iOS has storage guidelines where not everything downloaded should end up in that folder.

Comment: Thanks Rolf Winter, do you have any suggestion to access other standard folders contents: like downloaded music?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just look at the documentation link in my answer. There you will find everything you need such as, MusicLocation, MoviesLocation, PicturesLocation....