# No files found on iOS devices Qt Creator C++ QStandardPaths::standardLocations(QStandardPaths::DownloadLo‌​cation);

Tags: c++, ios, qt

I am using Qt Creator C++ QStandardPaths::standardLocations(QStandardPaths::DownloadLo‌​cation); to reach the user's files but it returns no files found on iOS devices.  Here is my code so far:

```
const QStringList
mPathList = QStandardPaths::standardLocations(QStandardPaths::DownloadLo‌​cation);
mPath = QString("%1").arg(mPathList.first());
dirmodel = new QFileSystemModel (this);
dirmodel->setFilter(QDir::AllDirs | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);
dirmodel->setRootPath(mPath);
```

Answer (score 0):

On iOS all apps lives in own sandboxes and you never get a direct access to things/files outside your app.

To do so you need to call native iOS API from your app at runtime. 
Also better don't save paths to use them next time your app is started because iOS generates hash based paths for apps in sandobox and they can change next time you run your app.

here is example how to call native iOS code in Qt.

create `ios_utils.mm` with following content and add it to source directory of your project:

```
#include "ios_utils.h"
#include <QStringList>
#include <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#include <qpa/qplatformnativeinterface.h>


QStringList getiOSHomeFolder()
{
    QStringList retval;

    NSString *item;
    NSArray *contents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:NSHomeDirectory() error:nil];

    for (item in contents)
    {
        retval.append(QString::fromNSString(item));
    }

    return retval;
}
```

create `ios_utils.h`:

```
#ifndef IOSUTILS_H
#define IOSUTILS_H


#ifdef Q_OS_IOS

QStringList getiOSHomeFolder();

#endif // Q_OS_IOS

#endif // IOSUTILS_H
```

and somewhere in your Qt code:

```
#include "ios_utils.h"

qDebug() << getiOSHomeFolder();
```

Comment: Thanks Xplatforms, trying your suggestion I got an error that is solved on this post (https://forum.qt.io/topic/26706/how-can-i-include-qpa-qplatformmenu-h-in-qt5/3), even though after fixing it, still no files are found (Documents, Downloads...)?

Comment: very strange, you should get a list of files and folders from user home folder. Check NSFileManager returned error.

Comment: Thanks so much Xplatforms, I got a list of my png files inside the app (icons and launchsplash mages)  ... actually am looking to get the files outside the app... do you have any suggestions?